# Merging two arrays to form new data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
var xArr = [];
xArr.push('FIRST NAME');
xArr.push('LAST NAME');
xArr.push('AGE');
```

And...

```
var yArr = [];
yArr.push('JOHN');
yArr.push('SMITH');
yArr.push('28');
```

Without depending on any kind of looping statement, or converting this into Object, is it possible to concatenate 1st element to 1st element, 2nd element to 2nd element, etc..?

Output would be:

```
var newArr = [ 'FIRST NAME = JOHN', 'LAST NAME = SMITH', 'AGE = 28' ];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: "Without depending on any kind of looping statement" — No. Doing something to every element in an array needs a loop. (Well. You could write out each array index by hand with otherwise copy/pasted code … but that would be terrible)

Comment: …even if that loop can be dressed up in various ways, e.g. ```xArr.map((v, i) => `${v} = ${yArr[i]}`)```.

Comment: xArr.map((a,i)=>{return \`${a} = ${yArr[i]}\`});

Comment: Might as well just make a static JSON file containing the correct format if we can't loop or convert to objects. Any particular reason `why` such restrictions are needed?

Answer (score 1):

> Without depending on any kind of looping statement, or converting this into Object, is it possible to concatenate 1st element to 1st element, 2nd element to 2nd element, etc..?

No, it's not possible, since you want to perform an action for every element in the array what needs a loop.

**NOTE:** You could do it manually using index's but that will be the wrong way since if you have a long array it will be difficult...

Answer (score 0):

regardless of requirement doing something like this
maybe stupid but okey

```js
xArr = [];
xArr.push('FIRST NAME');
xArr.push('LAST NAME');
xArr.push('AGE');
yArr = [];
yArr.push('JOHN');
yArr.push('SMITH');
yArr.push('28');
console.log(xArr);
console.log(yArr);

function merger(arr1,arr2){
var newArr=[];
for(var i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
newArr.push(arr1[i]+' = '+arr2[i]);
}
console.log(newArr);
return newArr;

}
merger(xArr, yArr)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/kp1gqae5/)

Comment: `Without depending on any kind of looping statement` ?

Comment: _Without depending on any kind of looping statement_ You're using the `for` loop !!!

Comment: regardless of requirement?